# POJO to Jackson with nested Objects

Tags: java, json, encoding, jackson, pojo

I want to convert a POJO to JSON (using Jackson-core-asl) of the format:

```
{"People" : 
[{"age":"1", "height":"5"}, {"age":"2", "height":"4"}] }
```

When I create the Person object in the POJO (with instance variables age and height), should I define the object as a separate POJO or should I provide a nested definition for the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `Person` POJO with `age` and `height`. Create another POJO that will have a `List`/`Set` or array of type `Person` named `People`. Deserialize your JSON for that type.

Comment: @user The action of converting a JSON String to a POJO.

Comment: Suppose it was just {"People" : {"age":1, "height": 2}}, and I was sure there would not be >1 Person object. Would I still need another POJO called people in order to deserialize? Could I nest the definition of the Person object?

Comment: @user3772960 The workaround so that you don't have to nest POJOs is uglier and requires configuration of the `ObjectMapper` and a specific, hardcoded string for the `People` key. The ideal would be getting rid of the `People` altogether.